# How to integrate handwriting input for numbers in my android app?

Tags: android, gesture, custom-keyboard, handwriting-recognition

My design team suggested that users have an extra option to input numbers in the form fields by switching android keyboard in to handwriting mode. For example user can able to enter 7000 by writing on keyboard.

How can I achieve this in my android application?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.myscript.com/ Its is paid for starter.

Answer (score 0):

THey may not be able to.  There's no promise that any keyboard has a handwriting mode.  Luckily you don't really need to-  if the user wants to switch to handwriting mode and the keyboard supports it, they can do so themselves.  But there is no way to open a keyboard in handwriting mode, because the Android OS doesn't have the idea of handwriting mode.  It doesn't know or care how a keyboard accepts input.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/phatware/WritePadSDK

http://www.heatonresearch.com/encog/

Try these libraries for android .